# What is this black flag in my code break bar?

Tags: sql-server

What is this? I fat fingered a key combo and I have no idea what it is..

I know its a dumb question but I tried googling it and nothing has come up. Maybe I do not kknow what to google to answer this for myself?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bookmark, toggled using `CTRL+K, CTRL+K`.

You can also navigate between bookmarks using `CTRL+K, CTRL+N` for *next bookmark*, and `CTRL+K, CTRL+P` for *previous bookmark*.

They're also available through the `Edit > Bookmarks` menu.

[image: SSMS Edit Bookmarks menu]